# VB.NET app giving memory exception 0xc0000005 in ntdll.dll

Tags: .net, vb.net, vb.net-2010

I am having some issues with a memory access exception in a VB.NET application that I am working on. I was hoping to get some insight here as none of the research I've done has helped me track down the problem.

**Background:**

I am converting a number of applications from VB6 to .NET 4.0. At the request of the client, I am doing a straight conversion and only refactoring when necessary to avoid injecting other issues into the code as I convert. Most apps are being compiled in Any CPU mode, though a few have to be compiled as x86 because of reliance on 32-bit PLC software or older hardware drivers. My development machine is Windows 7 64-bit.

**Issue:**

After successfully converting two apps, the third application is crashing at 
random places in the code. The exception isn't caught and I have to look at the  Looking at the event log I am seeing Exception 
code: 0xc0000005 on ntdll.dll, which I believe is a memory access exception. Since the application doesn't always crash in the same place, it is making it tough to track down. I have noticed that a lot of the errors occur during calls to ADODB (not always in the same place or on the same call), but it has also crashed on calls to form.ShowDialog().

The form where ShowDialog is being called writes some log information to the 
DB using ADODB. Though I haven't been able to confirm, I am guessing the exception within the form.ShowDialog() is happening during one of these ADODB calls. The crashing on the ADODB calls is happening in assemblies that are successfully being used in the other two apps that were converted and it doesn't consistently crash in the same place.

In my research on this I have seen that bad interop can cause this issue. Wondering if the ADODB COM calls are somehow causing the issue in this app even though these calls are fine in the other apps.

Some of the places I've observed calls that are apparently throwing this exception to the event log:

- newing an ADODB.recordset
- Creating a new parameter within a command.append
- connection.open calls

Would anyone have any ideas how I can narrow this down to possibly trace the 
issue to its root cause? I appreciate any help or insight you can provide.

Comment: Have you ruled out the possibility that you are having hardware problems on your development computer?

Comment: I haven't directly looked at hardware, but I did retest the previous app that uses these same calls and assemblies on this machine to make sure it didn't have any issues. Also, the code on this particular app isn't accessing the hardware directly. I will work on getting this running on another dev machine just to verify.

Comment: Do you know what original OS version it ran on? Perhaps you might try running it in compatibility mode for that OS or at least try an older OS. Right click exe, Compatibility tab, check "Run this program in compatibility mode for" and select OS.

Comment: To confirm the issue was ADODB, I refactored a couple of areas where it was consistently crashing and the crashing (at least in those areas) has ceased. So basically, I am just going to create a SQLClient version of those assemblies for this app, while keeping the orignal assemblies separate for the other two apps. If anyone has any other ideas around the root cause, I'd love to hear them still.

Answer (score 0):

Ah... PLC's that brings me back. If the manufacturer does not have an updated set of drivers you may be fighting an uphill battle. Whats likely occurring is that the newer OS is much faster or has more core or some combination of the two is causing "race" conditions in the driver code. This is especially true in communications where threading is often used. Since the driver code is likely written in C or C++ (unmanaged) you may not have much control over these conditions. You could try messing around with the threading model under which the application is running. If that improves stability, go with it.

[Apartment-Model Threading in Visual Basic 6](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa261361%28v=vs.60%29.aspx)

[DotNet MTA Thread Attribute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.mtathreadattribute.aspx)

[DotNet STA Thread Attribute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.stathreadattribute.aspx)

Worst case, you can spawn off a separate process that uses the driver and communicate with it from your main app using various "inter process communication" techniques. If it crashes you bring up another, but your main application will still keep running. You could even write the external process as a VB6 application in an absolute worst case basis.

Good luck.